# How to add admob banner under VIewFlipper?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have simple application.
It has LinearLayout, button on top and ViewFlipper with WebView + ListView after that.

If I add admob banner after flipper it will be pushed out from screen by flipper:(

I want banner to display on bottom of screen.

Sorry for my English:(

That's my xml (short-version)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout>
        { button is here }
    </LinearLayout>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView" />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adUnitId="gadsfadsfasdfsdf"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout 
put the AdsView as the Bottom and the ViewFlipper Above it

```
<XML


  <RelativeLayout...


   <AdView ...
      android:alignParentBottom="true"
      android:id="@+id/adsView"
   />
   <ViewFlippper 
       android:id="@+id/flipper"
       android:layout_above="@id/adsView"
   >
```

Comment: If I put AdView above ViewFlipper in vertical layout everything's ok, but I need to pit it UNDER flipper:(

Comment: i didnt say LinearLayout i said RealtiveLayout .. LinearLayout allows you to set which Controls below/above Control.

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. Now got it:) Thx.